# How to use `solve_for()` from `Symbolics.jl`?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, symbols, symbolic-math

```
using Symbolics, Latexify
copy_to_clipboard(true)
@variables R Y X_2 H_1 G_1 X_1 G_2 H_2 G_4 G_3 F
Symbolics.solve_for([(R - Y - X_2 * H_1) * G_1 ~ X_1,(X_1 - H_2 * Y) * G_2 ~ X_2,X_2 * G_3 + X_1 * G_4 + F ~ Y],[X_1,X_2,Y])
```

I tried to use the `solve_for()` to solve a linear equation set but after running it for 10 mins, it still haven't give me the result. I am really confused. Is there something wrong with my code or a bug of `Symbolics.jl`.

Comment: I run and get the `ERROR: StackOverflowError`

Comment: It is strange. It is just a linear problem. Using `sympy` I can get the result immediately.

Comment: Just to keep things connected: https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl/issues/381 is the Github issue tracking this